# Aircrack-ng: No /pentest/passwords/wordlists/darkc0de directories

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, files, directory

this is my fist question on this forum.
I'm currently using Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon and trying to run Aircrack-ng to show the password of my own Wi-Fi connection, I got the **Handshake** too. The problem is when I tried to run `aircrack-ng CrackFile.cap -w /pentest/passwords/wordlists/darkc0de` an error shows that there's no such directories on my system.

I know this question's already asked so many times, but no one provide good solution, at least for me. Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you probably copied that line from a hacking article that was based on BackTrack which may have had such a path, but since you said you are using Linux Mint, you don't have that. So it is exactly as the error says, you probably don't have that file.

But you don't need that particular wordlist to test whether aircrack-ng works on your own wifi.

It is your own wifi so you know the password, so you could just make a text file of your own, where each line is simply a password you make up, that you want aircrack-ng to try, and be sure you include your actual wifi password in there. You could have just two lines and the third line is your actual wifi password.

For example you can edit with

```
nano ~/mywordlist.lst
```

and inside you could just have

```
abc
123
xyz
myactualpassword
```

It doesn't have to be nano, whatever text editor you are comfortable with. It doesn't have to have `.lst` extension, it is just to make it easier for you to recognize it in the future as a list.

When you are done saving it then you can use aircrack-ng again, only this time point it to the wordlist you just made:

```
aircrack-ng CrackFile.cap -w ~/mywordlist.lst
```

Comment: Okay! I'm going to try it now, thanks for the information! @user454038

Answer (score 0):

as above, but a little more generic

download some txt/lst files that have passwords in them -lets say the classic `rockyou.txt` password list

save it say here : `/root/Passwords/`

add your actual password

```
echo "myactualpassword" >> /root/Passwords/rockyou.txt
```

now crack :

```
aircrack-ng [CaptureFileName].cap -w [/FullPath/][passwordfile.txt]
aircrack-ng CrackFile.cap -w /root/Passwords/rockyou.txt
```